# pure javascript, filter box doesn't filter properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, match

I have an array of devices, each device has own unique id, I wish to make searchBox which will filter by this id. So far I managed it partly, so it checks if character from input match character from device-id. However not in way I would want that, example below:

> id =35678; input.value = 5

it shouldn't work as first character is `3`

> id = 35679; input.value= 35

it should work as first character is same

Problem is in match/include function, but no really idea how to replace it to make it work

```
input_box.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  var search_result = this.value;
  var device = document.querySelectorAll('[device_id]')
  var array_of_devices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
       array_of_devices.push(device[i].getAttribute('device_id'))
  }
  array_of_devices.forEach(el => {
         if (!el.match(search_result)) {
           var not_matched = document.querySelector(`[device_id="${el}"]`)
           not_matched.style.display = "none"    
         } else {
          var matched = document.querySelector(`[device_id="${el}"]`)
          matched.style.display = "block"    
        }
     })
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.match` you can simply use `.indexOf` and check the index, if it 0 then the entered string is matching the device name from the begining.

```
array_of_devices.forEach(el => {
  // Condition below is changed to use indexOf
  if (el.indexOf(search_result) === 0) {
    var not_matched = document.querySelector(`[device_id="${el}"]`)
    not_matched.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    var matched = document.querySelector(`[device_id="${el}"]`)
    matched.style.display = "block"
  }
});
```

I would suggest you to build a string of device elements based on the search string and add it to your DOM instead of modifying the display properties. This is costing you a bunch of DOM operations which is computationally heavy.

Comment: I felt it's something simple but couldn't get idea, It works fine! thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**startsWith**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead of match

```js
let arr = ['35678', '451234', '45454', '56565']

let find = (value) =>{
  return arr.filter(id=> id.startsWith(value))
}

console.log(find(5))
console.log(find(35))
console.log(find(46))
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice each id in array should be string

```js
const ids = ['3575', '5555']
const found = value => ids.filter(i => i.indexOf(value, 0) === 0)
console.log(found(5));
console.log(found(35));
```